# Possibility to use 2 or more Ubuntu PCs to share the same work

Tags: 11.10, share

I was wondering if it is possible to share the resources between several PCs to do a common work. For example rendering a video/image or compiling something.

My question is more for the Desktop Ubuntu but if it is not possible then the Server version then. This is in regards with recent and updated versions of Ubuntu. What I mean with this is 11.10 and above.

Comment: A cluster? http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1030849 Maybe this helps, quite old i must say.

Comment: Also ye OLD Ubuntu Wiki on Clustering, which is less informative than the Thread above: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Clustering

Comment: You are scaring me Uri. I am going to update the question to include the words "Recent" and "Updated" ^^

Comment: For compiling, have a look at [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/107017/6969). For general resource sharing, e.g. for video processing, I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is possible, technically, but setting it up is by no means a simple operation. To my knowledge there are a few applications available in the repositories for the purpose, but results may vary.

For best results, you should actually use an application that natively supports clustering, such as some network renderers and compilers. I don't know of any of these off hand, but I know that for example it is possible to do this with Blender and custom renderers.

On the issue of Desktop vs Server - it is easier with the server version, seeing as you have various cloud computing solutions, but if you think about it, you could add these to the Desktop version as well, so maybe your solution would involve using server components on the Desktop.

Unfortunately, seeing as I have not done this before myself, I cannot (currently) give you concrete instructions. However, these links: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Clustering and http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1030849 as Uri pointed out, should come in helpful.