# How to speed up compilation of Ubuntu apps (make, cmake, gcc)

Tags: 11.10, compiling, gcc, make

I am compiling some programs here and I have 4 cores. Is there a way to tell `make`, `cmake` or `gcc` to compile using all cores or something to that affect?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If a package supports it you can use the `-j` flag to allow parallel jobs running, e.g.:

```
make -j8
```

More details on this flag can be found in the Stackoverflow question [Why does make -j perform better when it is passed a number larger than the number of cores available?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4802164/427545).

#### Distributed compilation

If you have multiple machines, give [distcc](http://www.distcc.org/) a go. On the involved machines, `sudo apt-get install distcc`. Assuming that your build machine is 192.168.1.1:

- on the helper machines, run:

  ```
  sudo distccd --log-file=/tmp/distccd.log --daemon -a 192.168.1.1
  ```
- On the build machine, before running `configure` or `cmake` you have to specify hosts that you want to use for the build process. Optionally, specify the number of simultaneous jobs after a slash (defaulting to 4):

  ```
  export DISTCC_HOSTS='localhost/4 192.168.1.2/8 192.168.1.3/8'
  ```

  Make the compiler use distcc:

  ```
  export PATH="/usr/lib/distcc:$PATH"
  ```

  Now `configure` or `cmake` the application and build with:

  ```
  make -j$(distcc -j)
  ```

  Note that if you've put `/usr/lib/distcc` twice in your PATH, it'll fail. Be sure to set `/usr/lib/distcc` only once in your `PATH`.

For more details, see the manual pages for [distcc(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/distcc.1) and [distccd(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/distccd.1).

Comment: OMG that J is good. I went from 15 minutes to less than 1. thanks L.

Comment: It can get faster with distcc, compilation of PHP was done in 2 minutes, the kernel was done in 3 minutes (three i5 machines)

Comment: Will try with distcc when i get to work. Was asking a similar question about this yesterday. Maybe you can help with it here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/106810/possibility-to-use-2-or-more-ubuntu-pcs-to-share-the-same-work

Comment: Running distccd as root seems like a bad plan. I've not used it for a few reasons but when I did I can't have used root because I didn't have permission on those machines.

Comment: @ams You do not need to run it as root. If you run it as root and want to switch users, use `distccd --user nobody`. Otherwise, it'll run under the user who executed it.

Comment: this answer needs more pump